# Warning: No shape table file present: shapetable

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to train a font in tesseract.
The commands i've used is as below:

`mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O eng.unicharset "eng.ocr1.exp2.tr"`

Warning: No shape table file present: shapetable

cntraining is working fine and font_properties file was also created without any problems.
I tried using:
`shapeclustering -F font_properties -U unicharset "eng.ocr1.exp2.tr"`

But got no output in return.

**I'm using**

tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20190708
leptonica-1.78.0
libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.3 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.5

**Please help.**

Comment: What is real problem? It is (just) warning. Which consequences has it for you? BTW: Why you do tesseract 3 training with tesseract 5(alpha)???

Comment: This is my first project on training a file.

Comment: if you can tell how to proceed it would be amazing